# QtCreator and doxygen

Tags: macos, qt, plugins, qt-creator, doxygen

I need QtCreator with the doxygen plugin, possibly a recent version.

It seems to be necessary to build QtCreator from source to do it, but the information I could find are quite outdated (e.g. http://wiki.qt.io/Doxygen_Plugin_for_QtCreator is about QtCreator 2.7.0, while today the latest version is 3.5.0 beta 1).

Is the latest plugin version compatible with the latest QtCreator?
Are those instructions still valid?
Are there any prebuilt QtCreator binaries with the Doxygen plugin already included?

Comment: have you asked the plugin author and checked plugin sources?

Comment: What you need from this plugin? Qt Creator already support syntax highlight and auto-completion for doxygen syntax constructions.

Comment: @Milovidov: I would like to be able to do what I can do with Doxywizard from inside QtCreator. And, e.g., right click on anything in the source code editor and jump to its Doxygen created graphical representation.

Comment: @nib: No, I did not check the plugin sources. I will do it as a last option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is indeed not much information about the plugin and I think is no longer maintained. But you can achieve pretty much everything without the plugin.

If you need to access your docs from your sources in Qt Creator, you can compile your regular doxygen-generated docs using qhelpgenerator and then import them into Qt Creator.

Add this to your Doxyfile:

```
GENERATE_QHP       = YES
QHP_NAMESPACE      = "my_namespace"
QCH_FILE           = "my_docs.qch"
QHG_LOCATION       = "path/to/qhelpgenerator"
```

Run `doxygen Doxyfile`.

And import the `my_docs.qch` file into Qt Creator (Tools/Options/Help/Documentation). You'll have access to your docs using F1.

You can even use recent versions of Qt Creator (3.6.0) and Doxygen (1.8.11).